# "Almost matching" using Tutte's Theorem

Tags: graph-theory

Got pretty strange question in the HW:

$G$ is a connected, simple graph with $|E(G)|$ even. I need to prove that there exist a partition of edges into pairwise disjoint pairs, where each pair is path of length 2. This must be done, using Tutte's theorem for perfect matching, somehow.

The only way I can see it can be done, is by contracting paths of length 2 into one edge, thus creating a graph, that will be more acceptable for Tutte's theorem. I can't see a clear way to do that, though.

Any clue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You might consider the graph $H$, with vertices $E(G)$ and an edge between $e_1, e_2 \in E(G)$ if $e_1$ and $e_2$ share a common vertex in $G$.  A perfect matching in this graph corresponds to a partition of $E(G)$ into disjoint pairs of edges forming paths of length 2.

Comment: @duncanm: That's precisely the edge graph referred to in my answer.

Comment: @joriki: yep --- didn't know what it was called, and was writing my comment at the same time you were writing yours.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider the [edge graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_graph) of $G$, which is likewise connected. By how much can you increase the number of its connected components when you delete one of its vertices (i.e. an edge of $G$)?

Comment: By at most 1. Very neat solution, thank you.